# Fetch Json data in local storage using loop on each json sub object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to store data locally for each sub object returned in json format like this -

```
key - name sectionType+number of section type ,  value - this object
```

My existing JS code:

```js
function syncAllSections_4(){
        user_sections= loggeduser_array.id;
        console.log(user_sections);
         var dict_4 = { userId: user_sections };
 $.ajax({
    url: 'http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/listSections.php',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dict_4),
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
    localStorage.setItem("sections",JSON.stringify(data.sections));
    //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sections")));
    
    var sections_array = [];
    sections_array  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sections"));
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error");
});
    }
```

The data format returned in Json is:

https://pastebin.com/4XBR23ua

This is how I want to save it in local storage:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried that has not worked?

Comment: I am trying to break the json and for that i need to call it in an array which i am doing but its not giving me the right length, this is how i am trying `var sections_array = [];
 sections_array = JSON.stringify(data.sections);
 console.log(sections_array.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that "sections" is already an array, so you shouldn't stringify it for array length. Also, the solution is quite straightforward (not tested but should work):

```js
function syncAllSections_4(){
  user_sections= loggeduser_array.id;
  console.log(user_sections);
  var dict_4 = { userId: user_sections };
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://funiks.com/adminv7/offline-api/listSections.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify(dict_4),
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if(data.status=="SUCCESS") {
      data.sections.forEach(section)=>{
        localStorage.setItem("SectionTypes"+section.sectionType,JSON.stringify(section));
      })
    }
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error");
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i also figured it out, i did it like this - `sections_array = data.sections;
 console.log(sections_array.length);
 for(i = 0; i < sections_array.length; i++){
 localStorage.setItem("section"+sections_array[i].sectionType,JSON.stringify(data.sections[i]));
 console.log(sections_array[i].sectionType);
 }`